# Dynamic pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am curious as to where to start to make something similar to [HERE](http://www.scotweb.co.uk/tartandesign/design/42163) as I cannot find any information about it. It may be fairly simple and im sorry if it is.

What I am hoping to replicate is the colour grid that generates based on the colours and size of the lines. I am looking to replicate the functionality of the application whereby when the user selects a line and changes the width of that line and it will then calculate the image. I have been looking around but cannot find information about how to replicate it. I may be searching for the wrong thing as javascript is not my strongest language.

I know of a roundabout way to do it with svg but where would I start for javascript/jquery?

[image]

Comment: Replicate it with code? With an image? Add some more information about what you want to achieve

Comment: @aurbano I am looking to replicate the functionality of the application whereby when the user selects a line and changes the width of that line it will calculate the image.

Comment: So, as you know how the solution with SVG works, you know how to replicate the interactive functionality and just wonder how to create the image with non-SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know of a way to do it with svg but where would I start for javascript/jquery?

Well, SVG would involve javascript as well, wouldn't it? You're just looking for different ways to display an image. None is native the javascript, that is just a programming language, you'd have to consider which API to use:

- There's nothing wrong with SVG! It even seems to be the easiest solution, maybe wrapping DOM code in some nice drawing library.
- It [has been demonstrated](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/) that such is possible with CSS3 background patterns, although I would consider this rather unusable
- Use the `<canvas>` element! This would be the most genuine HTML5 approach, and even though [the api is rather simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial) there exist mighty libraries.